# Is there a need to break down mini functions in my node.js controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, q

I have a controller for say users where I sign up my users. Do I really have to break up the steps of the sign up as below and do they all asynchronously seperately or is one big asynchronous call ok? Each step is kinda dependent on the previous.

- validate user
- create user
- create group
- add user to group
- login the user
- redirect the user.

Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Short version:

Apply low-coupling/high-cohesion principles, no one can tell you what you want or need, you're the only person who knows what you want to achieve.

Long version:

You are asking about architectural choices. There cannot be any good answer to that, you'll have to understand the problem yourself depending on other constraints you may have in your system and then apply OO design principles like SOLID/GRASP to understand the side effects of your choices and based on the software qualities you want to obtain take compromises that lead to useful solutions.